# Exposed filter list by tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view, which is listing nodes. I like to exposed filter it by tags (what is a taxonomy). But I like to show tags, what is relevant (has nodes) for the current view. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a field in view with name 
**Content: All taxonomy terms
Display all taxonomy terms associated with a node from specified vocabularies.**
That will display all terms associated with a node